# Shiny R different outputs when more than one input selected

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, shiny, reactive

In my **ui.R**I have sidebar with 3 inputs:

```
selectInput("category"...)
selectInput("program"...)
sliderInput("year"...)
```

My dataframe **df** has columns which combine **category** with **year** and **program** with **year** i.e : **prog1year, prog2year, category1year...**

When I choose selectInput **selectInput("category")** and **sliderInput("year")** my main dataframe **df** is filtered by **category** and **year** and **df1** is produced like:

```
df1 <- new_df %>% select_(.dots = c("City", paste0(input$category, input$year)))
```

and result is : **category1year, category2year...**

After choosing **selectInput("program")** and **sliderInput("year")** I need to return attention to main **df** and filter by **program** and **year** with result: **program1year, program2year...**

And when all 3 controls are choosen I need df to be filtered by columns named like **progyear** and **categoryyear**

For now I can filter by **category** and **year** but cannot make it work for program input.

Saying so I cannot call again main df:

```
  names(new_df)<- sub("category", "", names(df))
  new_df <- new_df %>% select_(.dots = c("City",paste0(input$category, input$year)))
  colnames(new_df) <- c("City", "Category")
```

Now when I want to use **selectInput("program")** it searches to **new_df** where columns with **prog1, prog2..** doesnt exist.

With respect to solution offered by **Pork Chop** tried :

```
  new_df <- reactive({})
  new_df <- new_df %>% select_(.dots = c("City",   paste0(input$category, input$year)))
  colnames(new_df) <- c("City", "Category")
  new_df <- new_df %>% select_(.dots = c("City", paste0(input$program, input$year)))
  colnames(new_df) <- c("City", "Program")
```

and I get error:

**no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "reactive"**

I am stucked here.

Can you please provide any minimal example with something like :

```
if (selectinput1 == choosen)...
```

Thank you

Comment: Look into the `%in%` operator to do your subsetting, looks to that is what you need

Comment: Hi Pork Chop. My main problem is not subsetting df but calling it again after it is filtered one time and turned to **df1**. I edited my post to make it more clear.

Comment: wrap the `new_df` as a reactive: `new_df <- reative({})` and then use that to further do your subsetting

Comment: Error no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "reactive"